# dplyr - find all max-values of y column and the corresponding x-values

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I have this data-set:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   type [1]
       x        y  type
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1  70.00 400.4200     1
2  72.00 400.4200     1
3  94.10 400.4310     1
4 105.60 400.4330     1
5 122.65 400.4360     1
6 132.20 400.4375     1
```

I've grouped the data by type and calculated the maximum y-value for each group using dplyrs summarize:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df %<>% group_by(type)

df_summary <- df %>% summarize(maximum = max(y))
```

which gives me the maximum value for each group, as intended.

```
> df_summary
# A tibble: 14 x 2
    type  maximum
   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1 400.4390
 2     2 400.4395
 3     3 400.4470
 4     4 400.4450
 5     5 400.4485
 6     6 400.4360
 7     7 400.4350
 8     8 400.4250
 9     9 400.4230
10    10 400.4235
11    11 400.4230
12    12 400.4260
13    13 400.4200
14    14 400.4145
```

My first question is: Is there a way to get the x-value which belongs to the max y-value using summarize? I used the calculated maximum values to get what I need from the original data utilizing a for-loop:

```
for (i in unique(df_summary$type)){
  if (i == 1){
    aux <- df[(df$type == i) & (df$y == df_summary$maximum[i]),]
    aux$value <- "maximum"
    df_summary2 <- aux
  } else {
    aux <- df[(df$type == i) & (df$y == df_summary$maximum[i]),]
    aux$value <- "maximum"
    df_summary2 <- rbind(df_summary2, aux)
  }
}

> df_summary2
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   type [14]
        x        y  type   value
    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <chr>
 1 139.70 400.4390     1 maximum
 2 143.30 400.4395     2 maximum
 3 426.70 400.4470     3 maximum
 4 151.50 400.4450     4 maximum
 5 146.20 400.4485     5 maximum
 6 151.20 400.4485     5 maximum
 7  99.90 400.4360     6 maximum
 8 445.40 400.4350     7 maximum
 9 323.40 400.4250     8 maximum
10 320.20 400.4230     9 maximum
11  97.90 400.4235    10 maximum
12  95.00 400.4230    11 maximum
13 108.55 400.4230    11 maximum
14  98.90 400.4260    12 maximum
15 108.70 400.4200    13 maximum
16 111.50 400.4145    14 maximum
```

Is there a way to get to the same result without using a loop?

the data:

```
structure(list(x = c(70, 72, 94.1, 105.6, 122.65, 132.2, 149.2, 
    162.2, 183.3, 188.8, 207.4, 222.9, 239.4, 247.4, 264.5, 275.5, 
    298.6, 302.6, 324.6, 336.6, 353.7, 360.7, 377.8, 392.8, 411.8, 
    417.8, 438.9, 451.9, 77.1, 86.65, 103.7, 115.2, 137.75, 139.3, 
    162.3, 173.4, 190.4, 200.4, 217.4, 230.5, 251.5, 256.6, 275.6, 
    290.6, 307.7, 315.7, 332.7, 343.8, 366.8, 369.8, 392.9, 403.9, 
    421, 429, 446, 70.3, 88.9, 94.4, 115.4, 128.5, 145.5, 154.6, 
    171.6, 183.6, 205.7, 207.7, 230.7, 241.8, 258.8, 267.8, 284.9, 
    297.9, 319, 325, 344, 359, 376.1, 383.1, 400.2, 411.2, 434.2, 
    438.2, 70.3, 81.4, 98.4, 105.9, 122.95, 138, 156.6, 162.6, 183.6, 
    198.6, 215.7, 224.7, 241.8, 252.8, 275.8, 277.8, 299.9, 311.45, 
    330, 340, 357, 370.1, 390.2, 396.2, 415.2, 430.2, 447.3, 454.3, 
    82, 93, 115.6, 119.1, 142.2, 153.2, 170.2, 177.75, 194.8, 209.85, 
    228.4, 234.4, 255.4, 268.5, 285.5, 294.6, 311.6, 322.6, 345.7, 
    347.7, 369.8, 381.8, 398.8, 407.8, 424.9, 437.9, 459, 75.8, 94.9, 
    109.9, 127, 134, 151, 162.1, 185.1, 189.1, 211.2, 223.2, 239.75, 
    247.3, 264.3, 279.4, 298.4, 303.9, 324.5, 337.5, 356.6, 367.1, 
    384.6, 396.6, 422.7, 424.7, 447.8, 458.8, 85.5, 95.05, 111.6, 
    125.6, 145.7, 151.7, 170.7, 185.8, 202.8, 209.8, 226.9, 238.4, 
    261, 265, 287, 299, 316.1, 323.1, 342.2, 357.2, 380.2, 385.3, 
    406.3, 419.4, 436.4, 445.4, 72.8, 84.3, 106.9, 108.9, 131.9, 
    143, 160, 169, 186.1, 199.1, 220.2, 226.2, 244.2, 259.75, 276.3, 
    284.3, 301.4, 312.4, 335.4, 338.95, 361.5, 372.6, 389.6, 397.6, 
    414.6, 429.7, 448.7, 453.8, 86.6, 99.7, 116.7, 126.25, 142.8, 
    154.8, 176.9, 178.9, 201.9, 213, 230, 239.5, 256.1, 270.1, 290.2, 
    296.2, 315.2, 332.2, 349.3, 356.3, 377.4, 388.4, 411.4, 414.5, 
    437.5, 448.6, 76.9, 84.9, 101.9, 117, 136, 141, 162.1, 175.1, 
    192.2, 201.7, 218.7, 230.2, 252.3, 254.3, 277.4, 288.4, 305.4, 
    314.95, 331.5, 345.5, 365.6, 371.6, 390.6, 405.7, 422.7, 429.8, 
    446.8, 457.8, 90, 93.5, 116.1, 127.1, 144.2, 152.2, 169.2, 184.2, 
    202.8, 208.3, 229.4, 242.4, 259.4, 268.5, 285.5, 297.5, 319.6, 
    321.6, 344.6, 355.7, 372.7, 381.8, 398.8, 412.3, 432.9, 438.9, 
    457.9, 82.3, 98.9, 106.4, 123.4, 134.5, 157.5, 161.05, 183.6, 
    194.6, 211.7, 219.7, 236.7, 251.8, 270.8, 275.8, 296.9, 309.9, 
    331, 340, 357, 368.55, 391.1, 393.1, 417.2, 429.2, 447.75, 457.3, 
    84.2, 97.2, 118.2, 123.75, 142.3, 157.85, 174.9, 182.4, 199.4, 
    210.5, 233.5, 237.5, 259.6, 271.6, 288.6, 295.7, 312.7, 327.8, 
    346.8, 352.8, 375.35, 390.4, 407.45, 421, 439.5, 451, 88.5, 90.5, 
    113.5, 124.6, 141.6, 150.6, 167.7, 180.7, 201.8, 206.8, 225.8, 
    240.9, 257.9, 265.9, 282.5, 294, 316.1, 320.1, 342.65, 354.2, 
    371.2, 378.2, 395.3, 410.3, 429.4, 434.4, 455.4), y = c(400.42, 
    400.42, 400.431, 400.433, 400.436, 400.4375, 400.4375, 400.4315, 
    400.42, 400.4175, 400.4075, 400.406, 400.409, 400.409, 400.411, 
    400.4075, 400.4065, 400.4065, 400.4105, 400.4135, 400.4215, 400.4215, 
    400.4265, 400.4295, 400.431, 400.434, 400.435, 400.4325, 400.4245, 
    400.428, 400.435, 400.4375, 400.439, 400.438, 400.432, 400.4285, 
    400.417, 400.411, 400.408, 400.4075, 400.4105, 400.41, 400.409, 
    400.4085, 400.412, 400.412, 400.4145, 400.4185, 400.4265, 400.427, 
    400.432, 400.4325, 400.4375, 400.4375, 400.436, 400.4155, 400.4205, 
    400.423, 400.4285, 400.4325, 400.441, 400.444, 400.436, 400.43, 
    400.4145, 400.4145, 400.4155, 400.4185, 400.4185, 400.4195, 400.4185, 
    400.419, 400.421, 400.421, 400.4255, 400.4325, 400.437, 400.4375, 
    400.4405, 400.443, 400.445, 400.445, 400.417, 400.422, 400.4265, 
    400.431, 400.4335, 400.4395, 400.443, 400.4415, 400.4295, 400.419, 
    400.416, 400.4145, 400.419, 400.421, 400.4195, 400.419, 400.42, 
    400.422, 400.4215, 400.421, 400.424, 400.426, 400.4285, 400.4295, 
    400.436, 400.439, 400.436, 400.433, 400.432, 400.4355, 400.436, 
    400.435, 400.445, 400.4465, 400.442, 400.442, 400.432, 400.425, 
    400.425, 400.426, 400.4285, 400.4265, 400.424, 400.424, 400.428, 
    400.4255, 400.422, 400.422, 400.422, 400.4235, 400.425, 400.428, 
    400.4345, 400.4345, 400.426, 400.4305, 400.434, 400.4345, 400.4325, 
    400.4335, 400.434, 400.433, 400.43, 400.4305, 400.4255, 400.424, 
    400.4265, 400.427, 400.4285, 400.424, 400.424, 400.425, 400.424, 
    400.421, 400.418, 400.417, 400.4215, 400.422, 400.4295, 400.43, 
    400.428, 400.424, 400.421, 400.4235, 400.424, 400.421, 400.425, 
    400.423, 400.422, 400.421, 400.421, 400.42, 400.423, 400.423, 
    400.426, 400.425, 400.422, 400.426, 400.428, 400.4275, 400.427, 
    400.426, 400.423, 400.4245, 400.425, 400.429, 400.433, 400.435, 
    400.4135, 400.414, 400.417, 400.4175, 400.416, 400.4175, 400.415, 
    400.414, 400.4155, 400.4185, 400.416, 400.4165, 400.421, 400.4225, 
    400.42, 400.419, 400.421, 400.423, 400.4225, 400.4205, 400.418, 
    400.4175, 400.4155, 400.4125, 400.413, 400.4185, 400.421, 400.419, 
    400.4165, 400.4175, 400.414, 400.4125, 400.416, 400.417, 400.413, 
    400.413, 400.414, 400.4145, 400.4155, 400.421, 400.42, 400.4195, 
    400.4175, 400.419, 400.421, 400.421, 400.4205, 400.4185, 400.4155, 
    400.413, 400.4105, 400.411, 400.4175, 400.4185, 400.4195, 400.42, 
    400.4215, 400.42, 400.419, 400.4175, 400.415, 400.4175, 400.4165, 
    400.4165, 400.415, 400.414, 400.416, 400.4165, 400.4145, 400.416, 
    400.416, 400.416, 400.414, 400.4115, 400.408, 400.4085, 400.4045, 
    400.4015, 400.406, 400.4065, 400.4065, 400.405, 400.4225, 400.4225, 
    400.42, 400.419, 400.422, 400.419, 400.4185, 400.417, 400.4185, 
    400.4155, 400.4185, 400.4175, 400.42, 400.4185, 400.416, 400.417, 
    400.42, 400.42, 400.417, 400.4125, 400.4105, 400.4105, 400.405, 
    400.4065, 400.409, 400.411, 400.409, 400.4215, 400.426, 400.4235, 
    400.4195, 400.4215, 400.4185, 400.42, 400.42, 400.4195, 400.416, 
    400.4165, 400.4175, 400.4195, 400.4195, 400.4185, 400.4175, 400.4185, 
    400.4185, 400.415, 400.414, 400.409, 400.4065, 400.406, 400.4065, 
    400.4095, 400.41, 400.4075, 400.415, 400.4165, 400.416, 400.413, 
    400.417, 400.414, 400.412, 400.411, 400.414, 400.4125, 400.413, 
    400.414, 400.4155, 400.4155, 400.414, 400.413, 400.415, 400.416, 
    400.4125, 400.411, 400.4065, 400.4065, 400.402, 400.4045, 400.4085, 
    400.407, 400.4125, 400.4125, 400.4115, 400.4085, 400.411, 400.409, 
    400.4025, 400.4035, 400.4055, 400.4055, 400.408, 400.404, 400.4085, 
    400.4085, 400.402, 400.4055, 400.4085, 400.41, 400.4045, 400.4035, 
    400.405, 400.4045, 400.3995, 400.4025, 400.403, 400.405, 400.4045
    ), type = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 
    13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
    13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    14, 14, 14, 14)), .Names = c("x", "y", "type"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -379L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: perhaps `df %>% group_by(type) %>% slice(which.max(y))`

Comment: How do you handle ties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to `slice` the row that have the `max` value of 'y' for each 'type'

```
df %>%
   group_by(type) %>% 
   slice(which.max(y)) %>%
   mutate(value = "maximum")
```

---

If there are ties, then use `==` to compare the 'y' with `max` of 'y', `filter` the rows or `slice`

```
df %>%
    group_by(type) %>% 
    filter(y == max(y)) %>% 
    #slice(which(y==max(y))) %>%
    mutate(value = "maximum")
```

Comment: Your second solution is what I did hence my question about ties in the comments

Comment: The second approach returns an empty dataframe, so I guess I do not have ties. The first approach returns a maximum for every group, but if you check  my desired output you'll see that some groups have two maximum values at seperate x-positions.

Comment: @brettljausn  I am using `dplyr_0.7.4`  It is not giving me empty dataframe based on the dput you gave.  What do you want to do with the ties

Comment: You're right, my mistake! Thank you very much, works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Or a combination of `arrange` and `slice`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  arrange(y) %>% 
  slice(n())
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   type [14]
        x        y  type
    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 149.20 400.4375     1
 2 137.75 400.4390     2
 3 438.20 400.4450     3
 4 156.60 400.4430     4
 5 153.20 400.4465     5
 6 109.90 400.4345     6
 7 445.40 400.4350     7
 8 312.40 400.4230     8
 9 332.20 400.4210     9
10 101.90 400.4215    10
11  93.50 400.4225    11
12  98.90 400.4260    12
13 142.30 400.4170    13
14  90.50 400.4125    14
```